# gridbadlayout vertical gaps

Tags: java, user-interface, gridbaglayout, gaps-in-visuals

I'm making a panel with som buttons on it. 
[image: this is what it looks like now.]

But i want the buttons to touch each other, in other words, I want the vertical gaps to dissapear. But the buttons shouldn't be resized. How can I go ahead to do this?

My code:

```
this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    constraints.gridwidth = 2;
    constraints.weightx = 1D;
    constraints.weighty = 1D;
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    int row = 0;
    for (MainAction actie : mainActions) {
        constraints.gridy = row;
        row++;
        SelectedActionButton but = new SelectedActionButton(selectedActionModel, actie);
        this.add(but, constraints);

    }
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.weightx = 0.5D;
    row *=2;
    for (AbstractAction actie : objectActions) {
        constraints.gridy = row/2;
        constraints.gridx = row%2;
        row++;
        SelectedObjectButton but = new SelectedObjectButton(selectedObjectModel, actie);
        but.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        this.add(but, constraints);
    }
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line

```
constraints.weighty = 1D;
```

to

```
constraints.weighty = 0D;
```

will fix your issue.

**Update**: to align all buttons north you may add an additional component in the last row eating all available space:

```
constraints.weighty = 1D;
constraints.gridy = row;
this.add(Box.createGlue(), constraints);
```

Comment: oh yups, that kinda seems to work :D only one issue now, how can i make sure the buttons are north? cuz they are centerred now